# Android recyclerview disable scroll

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have 1 recycler view with each item is full screen . in each item I have a button "NEXT". I don't want user to be able to swipe on recycler view to scroll to new item but can only click on next button to go to next item. Can anyone help me on this issue. or any other solution than recycler view. I tried some ways like set layoutManager canScrollHorizontal to False but it also can't scroll to next item when I click "NEXT" button. tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Custom `LinearLayoutManager` to your RecyclerView

**Custom LinearLayoutManager Code:**

```
public class RecyLinearLayoutManager(var context: Context?) : LinearLayoutManager(context) {
    private var isHorizontalScrollEnabled = false
    private var isVerticalScrollEnabled = false

    fun setHorizontalScrollEnabled(isHorizontalScrollEnabled: Boolean) {
        this.isHorizontalScrollEnabled = isHorizontalScrollEnabled
    }

    override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean {
        return isHorizontalScrollEnabled && super.canScrollHorizontally()
    }

    fun setVerticalScrollEnabled(isVerticalScrollEnabled: Boolean) {
        this.isVerticalScrollEnabled = isVerticalScrollEnabled
    }

    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
        return isVerticalScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically()
    }
}
```

**Set Layout Manager to Recycler View:**

```
    val linearLayoutManage = RecyLinearLayoutManager(this)
    linearLayoutManage.setHorizontalScrollEnabled(false);
    linearLayoutManage.setVerticalScrollEnabled(false)
    recyPdf.layoutManager = linearLayoutManage
```

**Add this code on Click on Next Button**

```
        val mLayoutManger = recyPdf.layoutManager as RecyLinearLayoutManager
        //To get the total Number of items visible on the screen
        val visibleItemCount = mLayoutManger.childCount
        if(currentItemVisi == 0){
            currentItemVisi = visibleItemCount - 1
        }
        currentItemVisi = (currentItemVisi + visibleItemCount) - 1
        //To get the total items loaded in the RecyclerView
        val totalItemCount = mLayoutManger.itemCount
        if(currentItemVisi<totalItemCount){
            linearLayoutManage.scrollToPosition(currentItemVisi-1)
        }
```

**Note:** `recyPdf` is My RecyclerView Name, You can change position in `scrollToPosition` according to your requirement.

Comment: it worked with ScrollToPosition but not work with smothScrollToPosition . do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

If they're fullscreen items (and it sounds like you're moving horizontally too) you probably want a `ViewPager` instead. Here's an example that shows you how to get nice animations too:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2

`ViewPager2` (the one used in the example) also has a `setUserInputEnabled` method, you can set that to false so the user can't swipe it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to disable scroll by user:

```
  recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          return true;
      }
  });
```

Another solution can be as you described, but you can temporarily enable scroll when user click Next

```
public class MyLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
 private boolean isScrollEnabled = true;

 public MyLayoutManager (Context context) {
  super(context);
 }

 public void setScrollEnabled(boolean flag) {
  this.isScrollEnabled = flag;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
  return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollHorizontally();
 }
}
```

Then call setScrollEnabled when you need